# Distant train in Argentine pampa

Tags: argentina

Hello friends and artists. I'm currently working in a medium size animation film about the troubled life of Eva Perón (Evita). During the opening shot we see a large steam train moving through the pampa (a native word for emptyness) which is a large plain, with no slopes, trees or anything at sight. I need this train to sound distant, and when the camera jump-cuts closer, go along. Combining 2 tracks (roads and railroads with the more random sounds of metal squeaks and breaks) seems to work. All that's missing is the distance. You guys had a situation like this before? Any ideas?
Thanx a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the more articulate sounds, like metal squeaks and brakes for the close up stuff, as the ear often picks up on more detail as a sound is closer to it. Perhaps more steam chug and rumble for the far away shot and introduce the rail sounds as the train approaches.

As far as mixing, I would experiment with cutting a bit of the high frequency of your effects in the distance to sell perspective. Also, sounds tend to be more mono and in the distance and gradually open up in the 5.1/stereo field as they approach. Use width and panning to sell this. And don't be afraid of reverb or delay. They are your friend.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In short terms: Mixing is the key. 
I've made a lot of shortfilms that include steam trains and stuff. So going to the field and living the experience could be helpful. Also the details may vary depending on the image and the feeling of it. Different shots different aproaches to them. Regards!!